# Using stringstream and stream operator (>>) to put buffer data into specific data types?

Tags: c++, c++11

As the title says, I'm doing input validation in C++ (in this case, for an int). I'm using a stringstream object to getline from the user, using the stringstream to assign to a variable with the stream operator, like so:

```
if (sStream >> validInteger) {
    if ((sStream >> input)) {
         code code code
    }
}
```

So in the first if statement, I'm getting the stringstream object I've created, and putting it into an integer type. If I use the stringstream to put a char into that integer type, the statement will return false and it won't actually assign to the integer, as expected in this situation.

I know that if you try to assign a char literal to an int with the assignment operator, it will just cast to the ASCII int value for that char (like int charInt = 'c' works fine and assigns the ASCII value)

So this means there is logic built into the sStream >> validInteger statement to not cast the data type, and to return false and to not actually assign the data to that variable.

My question is in regards to the logic for this statement. Where is this logic built in? Is the logic to return false and not assign within the stream operator (>>) or the stringstream object?

I've tested this with iostream and fstream objects like cin and ifstream, and they perform the same way. But is this logic built into cin and fstream as well? Or is it just in the stream operator (>>)?

My code is functional and everything works as expected, I just wanted to clarify how C++ operators/objects actually work in this case for my own knowledge.

Comment: The design of C++ iostreams library is awful. Just use flex/bison, ANTLR or boost::spirit.

Comment: All input streams inherit this behaviour from [std::istream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) and it's `operator>>`.

Comment: This question maybe more applicable to Code Review Stack Exchange site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `operator>>` doesn't share any logic with what the compiler does to parse C++ source code, so you shouldn't expect it to act like an assignment operator appearing in source code.  There's no logic needed to not do type conversion, because there's no type-checking logic in `operator>>`.  It treats the user input as text data, not as C++ code.

Comment: I think I understand. Is the fact that there's no type conversion why it doesn't "push" into a variable of a different data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate, you can always check [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com). At the top of [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) you can see the inheritance tree, and compare with other input streams to see the first shared ancestor. Then, look at it:

The [`istream::operator>>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) states

> (1) arithmetic types
>
> > Extracts and parses characters sequentially from the stream to interpret them as the representation of a value of the proper type,
> >     which is stored as the value of val.
> >         Internally, the function accesses the input sequence by first constructing a sentry object (with noskipws set to false). Then (if
> >     good), it calls num_get::get (using the stream's selected locale) to
> >     perform both the extraction and the parsing operations, adjusting the
> >     stream's internal state flags accordingly. Finally, it destroys the
> >     sentry object before returning.

so quite a bit under the hood. A proper type checking is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The operation:

```
   sStream >> validInteger
```

returns the stream object, not true, false or some error. The state of the the stream object (or any other stream object types in the iostream library) can be converted to something that can be tested with an if(), or other conditional construct, via  an operator overload of the `void *` conversion in earlier versions of C++, and a `bool` conversion in the latest versions.